# Building a Templated Container Class

Tags: c++, c++11, gcc, clang

As a part of my custom object system I would like to have a Container class that just wraps a third party object so that they can be integrated into my container system.

Assuming I have the following third party object,

```
class Point { 
public:  
  int x;  
  Point(int y = 0) : x(y) {}  
  int value() { return x; } 
};
```

Container class,

```
template <typename T, typename... Args> class Container{  
   T dat; 
public:  
   Container(const Args &... args) { dat = T(args...); }  
   T data() { return dat; } 
};
```

I am trying to provide the following api,

```
    Container<Point> v = Container<Point>(1);
```

I am trying to pass the parameters passed to the value constructor directly to type T constructor.

EDIT: I get a compiler error `candidate expects 0 arguments, 1 provided errors`

Comment: So... what issue are you facing?

Comment: Container() constructor??!! shouldn't be Value()?

Comment: @Quentin I does not work. I get a bunch of `candidate expects 0 arguments, 1 provided` errors

Comment: @chedynajjar right copy/paste error fixed.

Comment: @HamzaYerlikaya please include the exact errors in your question then, as well as enough code to reproduce them.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to make the constructor templated on `Args...`, not the class:

```
template <typename... Args>
Container(Args&&... args) : dat(std::forward<Args>(args)...) { }
```